# Dynamic data structures in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am trying to improve the performance of my VBA program, because it takes forever to perform some table operations.

During the programs runtime I am trying to store data in worksheets, but the write-operations take for ever and I would like to store this data dynamically instead of writing it into a worksheet to reduce the time it needs to run.

I was thinking about using arrays instead of the worksheets to store the data but I am not quite sure whether this will work because I do not know how many rows/columns my table exactly has.

Here my code, any help is appreciated!

```
Public row As Long
Public rowMax As Long
Public startRow As Integer
Public materialType As String
Public filter As String
Public col As Integer
Public colMax As Integer
Public isUsed As Boolean
Public a As Integer

Sub bestimmeObFelderGenutzt()
    Debug.Print ("bestimmeObFelderGenutzt:begin" & " " & Now())
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        filter = "I"
        startRow = 2
        rowMax = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
        colMax = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        materialType = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(filter & startRow).Value

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Nutzung"

        For col = 1 To colMax
            Sheets("Nutzung").Cells(1, col + 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, col).Value
        Next col

        For row = 2 To rowMax
            Sheets("Nutzung").Range("A" & row).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value
            Sheets("Nutzung").Range("B" & row).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & row).Value
                For col = 1 To colMax
                    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col)) = False Then
                        isUsed = True
                        Sheets("Nutzung").Cells(row, col + 2).Value = 1
                    Else:
                        Sheets("Nutzung").Cells(row, col + 2).Value = 0
                    End If
                Next col
        Next row
    End With
    Debug.Print ("bestimmeObFelderGenutzt:end" & " " & Now())
End Sub



Sub findeUngenutzteSpalten(ByVal materialType As String, pos As Integer)
    Debug.Print ("findeUngenutzteSpalten:begin" & " " & materialType & " " & Now())
    With Sheets(materialType)
        rowMax = Sheets(materialType).Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
        colMax = Sheets(materialType).Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Sheets("Auswertung").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Spaltenüberschrift:"
        Dim a As Integer
        For a = 1 To colMax
            Sheets("Auswertung").Cells(a + 1, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, a).Value
        Next a

        Sheets("Auswertung").Cells(1, pos + 1).Value = materialType

        For col = 3 To colMax
            For row = 2 To rowMax
                    If Sheets(materialType).Cells(row, col).Value = 1 Then
                        Sheets("Auswertung").Cells(col - 1, pos + 1).Value = "Ja"
                        GoTo WeiterCol
                    Else:
                        If row = rowMax Then
                            Sheets("Auswertung").Cells(col - 1, pos + 1).Value = "Nein"
                        Else:
                            GoTo WeiterRow
                        End If
                    End If
WeiterRow:
            Next row
WeiterCol:
        Next col
    End With
    Debug.Print ("findeUngenutzteSpalten:end" & " " & materialType & " " & Now())
End Sub

Sub kopiereZeilen(ByVal materialType As String)
    Debug.Print ("kopiereZeilen:begin" & " " & materialType & " " & Now())
    With Sheets("Nutzung")
        rowMax = Sheets("Nutzung").Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = materialType

        Sheets("Nutzung").Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(materialType).Cells(1, 1)
        Dim unusedRow As Long

        For row = 2 To rowMax
            unusedRow = Sheets(materialType).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).row
            If Sheets("Nutzung").Cells(row, 2).Value = materialType Then
                Sheets("Nutzung").Cells(row, 2).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(materialType).Cells(unusedRow, 1)
            End If
        Next row
    End With
    Debug.Print ("kopiereZeilen:end" & " " & materialType & " " & Now())
End Sub

Sub allesZusammen()

    Debug.Print ("Hauptaufruf:begin" & " " & Now())

    Dim types(10) As String
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim pos As Integer

    bestimmeObFelderGenutzt

    types(0) = "A"
    types(1) = "B"
    types(2) = "C"
    types(3) = "D"
    types(4) = "E"
    types(5) = "F"
    types(6) = "G"
    types(7) = "H"
    types(8) = "I"
    types(9) = "J"
    types(10) = "K"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Auswertung"

    For Each element In types
        kopiereZeilen (element)
        pos = Application.Match(element, types, False)
        findeUngenutzteSpalten element, pos
    Next element
    Debug.Print ("Hauptaufruf:end" & " " & Now())

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `Application.ScreenUpdating` method. See excel help for use.

Comment: yeah this helped a lot, now the program runs 29% faster! But I need it much more faster because even with the 29% less time it runs approximately 5 hrs

Comment: You are iterating over every cell. Try filtering on criteria first, then copying ranges as a whole. Or use a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare dynamic arrays. The general syntax is:

```
Dim Values() As Long
```

To use the array, you must first re-dimension it to the size you want. For example this declares a two-dimensional array of 3 x 5 values (zero based):

```
ReDim Values(2, 4)
```

If you want to size based on variables then use something like:

```
ReDim Values(myrowsize, mycolumnsize)
```

You can grow (or shrink) the array dynamically by using this syntax:

```
ReDim Preserve Values(2, mynewsize)
```

Note, that you can only re-dimension the last index of the array. So this is not allowed:

```
ReDim Preserve Values(mynewsize, 4)
```

But this is probably ok in your case, as you have a fixed number of columns.

It is perfectly ok to declare the dynamic array as a UDT. For example:

```
Type UDTInfo
    valueA As Long
    valueB As Long
End Type

Sub test()
    Dim Values() As UDTInfo

    ReDim Values(2, 4)

    ReDim Preserve Values(2, 5)

End Sub
```

You can access the array in the normal way:

```
x = Values(1, 2)
```

You can copy one dynamic array to another directly, as long as the types and number of dimensions match (size doesn't matter):

```
Dim Values() As Integer
Dim Results() As Integer

Results = Values
```

And lastly, you can pass dynamic arrays to and from functions in the following way:

```
Function SomeFunc(ByRef Values() As Long) As Long()
    Dim ReturnValues() As Long

    ReturnValues = Values

    SomeFunc = ReturnValues
End Function
```

Note, you only pass dynamic arrays ByRef but **not** ByVal.

Comment: Glad to help. Hopefully it's a lot faster.

Comment: Yeah, it almost feels like time travel :D